# How would one handle different return types when overriding abstract method

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract, return-type

Say I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected abstract ReturnA Foo();

    public void UseFoo()
    {
        var foo = Foo();

        if (foo != null)
        {
            //logic here
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override ReturnA Foo()
    {
        // Implementation specific code that returns ReturnB instead.
    }
}

public class C : A
{
    protected override ReturnA Foo()
    {
        // Implementation specific code that returns ReturnC instead.
    }
}

public class ReturnA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnB
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnC
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I know that C# does not support derived return types, but this is not what I need either.
Classes B and C are implementation specific and therefore their return types have nothing to do with eachother.

The reason why I would want to handle this, is because the method UseFoo in class A may have some generic checks and other generic logic, that has nothing to do with the returned object itself.
So I want to "outsource" only the code that is implementation specific and not have to instead make UseFoo abstract and have every implementation write the same generic code.

Is there any way to solve this at all?

EDIT: Neither `ReturnC` nor `ReturnB` are derived from `ReturnA`. Updated with examples.

Comment: If only implementations are varied, why not returning Interface of `ReturnA` ? If something prevents you from doing it, explain your detail use case.

Comment: Your example is unclear to - me - partly because we can't see declarations of ReturnA, ReturnB or ReturnC. Do ReturnB and ReturnC actually derive from ReturnA? If you don't need to do anything with the result other than test for nullity, could you either change the return type to `object` or just have a method returning `bool` instead? A more complete example would really help.

Comment: @JonSkeet Was probably unclear. ReturnB and ReturnC are implementation specific and have nothing to do with eachother, which is why I left any implementation of them out. But returning object might actually be exactly what I need!

Comment: They may have nothing to do with *each other*, but do they derive from ReturnA? It would really help if your concrete example could be complete and show what you've tried and what problems it causes at the moment - because at the moment, this question is pretty unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet Updated to be more clear :)

Comment: Well somewhat. Why do you currently have an abstract method that's meant to return ReturnA at all? Do you expect to actually need to implement that in C and B? What if other code expects to be able to call Foo and use the returned ReturnA? Does UseFoo *really* only need to check for nullity?

Comment: That was the main reason returning object made sense. I would never need to return the type ReturnA. The return type will always be specific to the implementation. UseFoo will never have to anything with the returned object other than check for nullabillity.

Comment: What about using the next options: **1.** Make class `A` generic (`class A<TReturn>`) with method `abstract TReturn Foo();`. Derive from it other classes, for example: `class B : A<ReturnB>` with method `override ReturnB Foo();`. *OR*  **2.** Change method `Foo` to return `object`. Do these options fit your requirements?

Comment: @IliarTurdushev Returning object seems to fit my needs :)

Comment: Or change the method to return bool, to check a condition instead of returning an object that won't actually be used. That makes the API more closely reflect what you're actually trying to achieve.